# Можете полностью объяснить полностью строку с translated?

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';

let messages = {
   "Hello, {0}!": "Привет, {0}!" 
};


function i18n(strings, ...values) {  
    let pattern = "";  
    for(let i=0; i<values.length; i++) {  
        pattern += strings[i] + '{' + i + '}';   
    }   


    pattern += strings[strings.length-1];

    let translated = messages[pattern];

    return translated.replace(/\{(\d)\}/g, (s, num) => values[num]);
}

let name = "Вася";

alert( i18n`Hello, ${name}!` );
```

Comment: какую? в коде две строки с  `translated`

Comment: Интересная реализация локализации.

Comment: посмотрите тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: @A.Gusev, Что за прикол задавать вопрос на вопрос?! Если сами не знаете, то и не надо такое спрашивать! А знаете - напишите!

Answer (score 0):

`return translated.replace(/\{(\d)\}/g, (s, num) => values[num]);`

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но поведение тут такое -

1. `translated` получает значение по индексу, т.е. в данном случае вернет `Привет , {0}`
2. `RegExp` вытаскивает вот такую последовательность `{цифра}` из строки `messages` (которое потом выставлено в `translated`). Т.е. например `Привет {0} -> {0}`
3. Затем заменяет его значением, вычисляемым в стрелочной функции, т.е. если `values` имеет 1 элемент (т.е. индекс `0`), функция вернет значение `values[0]` (в `values` в данном случае будет 'Вася') и подставит вместо `{0}` в `translated`.
4. В итоге вместо пришедшего на вход в translated `Привет, {0}`, будет `Привет, Вася`.

Т.е. сам `RegExp` просто возвращает только вхождения цифр в искомой строке, а `replace` заменяет его значением из вычисляемой функции.